# What are the most commonly used Chinese syllables?

Tags: syllables, chinese, frequency

There are about 1200 or so unique (includes all tones) Mandarin Chinese syllables, according to some source I read a while back based off the [Unihan database](http://unicode.org/charts/unihan.html).

For my applications I'm limited to using only 1/3 of those 1200 syllables, but I do realize that there are a fair amount of obscure syllables that are hardly used in normal conversations. The problem is, how much of that 1200 is obscure and not so useful? How would being limited to using only 1/3 of it limit my speech? Would I be conversational? Or brought to the level of a grade schooler? Or even worse, unable to hold any sort of conversation?

Comment: What sort of application do you have that can only handle 400 syllables?

Comment: its a hardware related issue that limits the amount of files I can use. I plan to make individual audio files for each syllables so that my program can speak chinese syllable by syllable.

Comment: You asked many questions, can you compress them in one?

Comment: I only asked one question essentially, what level of speech would 1/3 of the syllables provide me?

Comment: I see, I didn't understand it from the question. :)

Comment: I was wondering, how come you can only do it in syllables and not characters? Wouldn't it be easier for you to calculate? Maybe I'm missing something so I wanted to ask.

Comment: I think you ought to rethink your design; even sstoring neutral-toned syllables and adding the tones afterward would gain you a lot in terms of space efficiency, if your hardware can efficiently handle basic pitch-shifting.

Comment: @Alenanno there are thousands of characters in chinese, though since all characters are single syllabled it makes no difference. Unless I save like the audio of more than one character in one file, but that limits the usage I could have for that specific file.

Comment: @JonPurdy I'm storing the tones of syllables that most frequently occurs to maximize the space I have, but my hardware, which is just a microcontroller, can't do such complex functions like pitch-shifting, even if it could it would be very awkward sounding.

Comment: @mugetsu: If your samples are good enough, perhaps store initials and finals separately. Only finals need tones.

Comment: @JonPurdy, I assume you mean "onsets" and "codas," in which case your approach will sound less than natural, since segments are co-articulated to some degree and tone is suprasegmental (I'm not sure how much perceived degradation this will cause, though).  mugetsu, you will have to deal with tone sandhi (which see on Wikipedia) to achieve best results.  Luckily, Mandarin has relatively simple rules for this.

Comment: @mugetsu: I think you could go from the Level 1 Hanzi up seeing the actual syllables being used until you reach 400, and see what level you reached. The rapport is not 1:1, considering many characters have the same syllable sound, such as 他 (*he*), 她 (*she*), 它 (*it*), for example.

Comment: @mugetsu: Not all characters are single-syllable. [(eg: 圕)](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3330)

Comment: @Aaron: Yes, just a minor slip of the brain, thanks.

Comment: What does this have to do with Linguistics?

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 wow never knew that. Though are there other examples? According to wikitionary this word has not gained wide spread acceptance, I'm pretty sure if I tried using this word no one would understand me, thus it really isn't relevant in common speech.

Comment: @Alenanno thats my last resort :/

Comment: @Aaron yes tone sandhi is expected, but thats something I have to fix case by case, even without fixing tone sandhi the meaning of the sentence isn't skewed

Comment: @magnetar you might want to look up the definition of Linguistics sir

Comment: @mugetsu: The word, as spoken, is very common. It's the character that's uncommon. But if you're trying to model Mandarin speech using characters to represent syllables, you'll run into problems, that being one of them. The article I linked to shows a few other multi-syllable characters.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 I must disagree on that point, it seems like these polysyllabic chars are very rare and can be replaced with multiple characters. As a native I've never heard of these things, so it really is true that the gov is trying to stamp them out. So when I have my hardware speak out tu shu guan it would see the pinyin and play the respective file for each  syllable. My speech to pinyin software will not deal with how the character is written. So I'm not exactly seeing the problems I will be running into...

Comment: @mugetsu I guess if you simply reject any problematic characters then you don't have any issues with mapping a character to its pronunciation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [this site](http://www.chinahighlights.com/travelguide/learning-chinese/pinyin-syllables.htm) I found the **413** most commonly used syllables in Chinese. They are 13 over your limit.

With these you can create thousands of characters, so the level will be pretty high, I think.

**When visiting that site**, you'll find 2 columns:

- the first one is the syllables list written in **pinyin**;
- the second column is the rough pronunciation according to the English rules.

---

Below I organized them for ease of reference (it's an image, I'm not sure you wanted just a list for reference or a txt file):

[image]

Comment: @mugetsu: This chart doesn't account for tone, so you actually have potentially 5x the number of entries here if you need to represent the tones.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 that's fine, I was able to go through the list and think of all the tones that are commonly used for each syllable. I managed to meet my limit to some degree, though there were a few significant sacrifices. But it's decent enough for common speech.